# Obtener el contacto del propietario del dispositivo en Android

Tags: java, android, contenedores

En la aplicación Contactos, el primero que muestra es del propietario.

¿Se puede extraer la información del contacto del propietario del dispositivo?

He buscado por todos los contactos disponibles del proveedor `ContactsContract.Contacts` y no veo en ningún caso que lo indexe.

¿Me pregunto, si se guarda en otro rincón o bien es de solo uso interno de la app contactos del sistema?

**Edición**

Busancdo por el SDK he econtrado como obtener los datos del propietario del dispositivo

```
public static SimpleContact TESTgetLocalProfile(Context context) {

    Uri PROFILE_URI = ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Profile._ID,
            ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Profile.PHOTO_URI,
            ContactsContract.Profile.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Profile.LOOKUP_KEY
    };
    final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + "= ?";
    String[] mSelectionArgs = {"10"};
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    // Build adapter with contact entries
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(PROFILE_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

    SimpleContact item = null;

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile._ID));
        item = new SimpleContact(contactId);
        item.setDisplayName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        item.setPhoto(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.PHOTO_URI)));
        item.setLookupKey(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.LOOKUP_KEY)));
        if (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
            //No ser como obtener el número
        }
        c.close();
    }

    return item;

}
```

#### Debug de campos:

```
D/ContactsHelper: columName: sort_key =Test User
D/ContactsHelper: columName: blocked =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: photo_uri =content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/9223372034707292161
D/ContactsHelper: columName: status_label =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: status_ts =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: status_res_package =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: display_name =Test User
D/ContactsHelper: columName: last_time_used =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: mimetype =vnd.android.cursor.item/name
D/ContactsHelper: columName: phonebook_label_alt =U
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data6 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: version =7
D/ContactsHelper: columName: photo_id =9223372034707292166
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data3 =User
D/ContactsHelper: columName: custom_ringtone =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: times_contacted =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: account_type_and_data_set =com.android.localphone
D/ContactsHelper: columName: dirty =1
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data7 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data15 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: raw_contact_is_user_profile =1
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data_set =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: phonebook_label =T
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data10 =1
D/ContactsHelper: columName: res_package =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: account_type =com.android.localphone
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data11 =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: display_name_alt =User, Test
D/ContactsHelper: columName: lookup =profile
D/ContactsHelper: columName: phonetic_name =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: last_time_contacted =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: contact_last_updated_timestamp =1505762023483
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data13 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: in_visible_group =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: chat_capability =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data9 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: carrier_presence =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data_sync1 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: sort_key_alt =User, Test
D/ContactsHelper: columName: contact_presence =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data_version =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: phonetic_name_style =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: name_raw_contact_id =9223372034707292163
D/ContactsHelper: columName: raw_contact_id =9223372034707292163
D/ContactsHelper: columName: send_to_voicemail =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data4 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data12 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: contact_status =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: contact_status_label =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: pinned =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: status_icon =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: status =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data1 =Test User
D/ContactsHelper: columName: phonebook_bucket =21
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data_sync2 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: contact_status_res_package =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: in_default_directory =1
D/ContactsHelper: columName: _id =9223372034707292163
D/ContactsHelper: columName: hash_id =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: is_super_primary =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data5 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: contact_id =9223372034707292162
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data8 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: is_primary =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data_sync4 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: has_phone_number =1
D/ContactsHelper: columName: display_name_source =40
D/ContactsHelper: columName: photo_file_id =9223372034707292161
D/ContactsHelper: columName: custom_vibration =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data_sync3 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: backup_id =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data14 =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: contact_status_ts =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: phonebook_bucket_alt =22
D/ContactsHelper: columName: mode =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: data2 =Test
D/ContactsHelper: columName: group_sourceid =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: starred =0
D/ContactsHelper: columName: photo_thumb_uri =content://com.android.contacts/contacts/9223372034707292162/photo
D/ContactsHelper: columName: times_used =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: contact_status_icon =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: contact_chat_capability =null
D/ContactsHelper: columName: account_name =PHONE
D/ContactsHelper: columName: sourceid =null
```

Lo que me falta es obtener el número de teléfono asociado, pero como que el contacto no está dentro del proveedor de contactos ni de rawcontacts, no lo puedo obtener.

Comment: Buena pregunta, esto es algo que traté de buscar a partir precisamente de ContactsContract, pero no existe un indicador que determiné cual es el contacto del dueño del dispositivo, agrego mi "solución".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En construcción...

Mas o menos he encontrado como obtenerlos, pero falta pulir...

```
public static SimpleContact TESTgetLocalProfile(Context context) {

    Uri PROFILE_URI = ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Profile._ID,
            ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Profile.PHOTO_URI,
            ContactsContract.Profile.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Profile.LOOKUP_KEY
    };

    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(PROFILE_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

    SimpleContact item = null;

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile._ID));
        item = new SimpleContact(contactId);
        item.setDisplayName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        item.setPhoto(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.PHOTO_URI)));
        item.setLookupKey(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.LOOKUP_KEY)));

        if (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {

            Cursor pCur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    // Retrieves data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY),
                    new String[]{
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_PRIMARY,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE
                    },

                    // Selects only email addresses or names
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? ",
                    new String[]{
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                    },

                    // Show primary rows first. Note that there won't be a primary email address if the
                    // user hasn't specified one.
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC"
            );

            if (pCur != null && pCur.moveToFirst()) {
                item.setPhoneNumber(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                pCur.close();
            }

        }
        c.close();
    }

    return item;

}
```

Código adaptado de [AccountUtils.java](https://gist.github.com/imminent/4061516)

Answer (score 1):

Mediante `ContactsContract` no existe una forma de obtener los datos del cliente, el dueño del dispositivo generalmente agrega su cuenta gmail, pero regularmente no su teléfono en los contactos, además no existe un indicador para determinar que contacto es el propietario.

Como opción para obtener la (o las) cuenta(s) del propietario:

```
final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
final Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

String[] emails = new String[accounts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
    emails[i] = accounts[i].name;
}
```

Comment: Acabo de encontrar eso, me parece que si se puede extraer, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile.html

Comment: Si deseas lo datos del propietario del dispositivo, ¿consideras comparar tu numero o nombre con todos los que obtiene y almacena el cursor?, eso podría ser otra opción pero necesitarías algún dato del usuario.

Comment: Solo quisiera obtener el _ID, displayNambe, photoUri, Number, más o menos lo tengo consultando el ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI